# Why does java service method successfully write out to a file but JUnit calling the same method in a unit test fail to write out?

Tags: eclipse, web-services, unit-testing, junit, fileoutputstream

I am using Java 7, JUnit 4.10.0, Mockito 1.9.5, and Eclipse Juno running in Windows 7 as my IDE. I am using Java EE annotations for my Java classes.  I have created a rest service and am running into an issue when one of my JUnit unit tests calls one of the bean's methods.

When the method *createOptFile* is executed in my webservice the FileOutputStream for file ft070r_999.opt is successfully created.  When my unit test calls this method I get back **java.io.FileNotFoundException: \appworx\twcis\wcisout\ft070r_999.opt (The system cannot find the path specified)**.

In this case I am passing in a HashMap containing a fully qualified UNIX type path of   **/appworx/twcis/wcisout/ft070r_999.opt** that the method digs out and uses. The FileOutputStream converts from UNIX style path to Windows style.  Both when called from the service and from JUnit the converted path is identical.  I deliberatly broke the webservice by using the path **\blah\appworx\twcis\wcisout\ft070r_999.opt**, which does not exist, just to get the same Exception and output to confirm that the path conversion is the same for both the service and the unit test - merely switching "/" to "\".

Here is my bean method:

```
@Stateless
public class HPExstreamBean {
    public String createOptFile(HashMap<String, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> returnHash, String report) throws IOException {
        String optFile = null;

        optFile = returnHash.get("files").get(0).get("content").split("[.]", 2)[0] + ".opt";

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(optFile));

        //
        //more code in here that is never reached because of Exception 
        //

        return optFile;
    }
}
```

Here is my unit test:

```
@Test
public void testCreateOptFileNotNull() {
    HPExstreamBean hpExstreamBean= new HPExstreamBean();
    String result = null;

    try {
        result = hpExstreamBean.createOptFile(returnHashTest, "test_report");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    assertNotNull(result);
}
```

Here is the top of the stack trace that comes back when the unit test aborts:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \appworx\twcis\wcisout\ft070r_999.opt (The system cannot find the path specified)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:212)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:165)
at com.pinnacol.solomongrundyservice.business.HPExstreamBean.createOptFile(HPExstreamBean.java:307)
at test.unit.HPExstreamBeanTest.testCreateOptFileNotNull(HPExstreamBeanTest.java:297)
```

I can't see where container management of the bean would lead to success since this isn't any kind of transaction that needs to be persisted, but am willing to be wrong as I am fairly new to Java.

Can anyone help me with figuring out why my unit test calling the bean method is failing?

Comment: The first thing I would do is print out the path of the file you are trying to open. I have often been surprised by the results of this. You will be too.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I actually did that and got back what I was expecting - \appworx\twcis\wcisout\ft070r_999.opt.  That directory does exists on my C: drive.

Comment: Upon further review you were right.  The problem ended up where my workspace is for Eclipse I think.  JUnit lives with the project on another drive than where my desktop is.  When the service itself runs the method it is running locally in my Eclipse session's server.  I figured it out by trying to create a new File right inside my unit test and see where it was pointing rather than in my service when being called by JUnit.

So, thanks for the response once again.